# Triple integral with spherical coordinates.

Tags: calculus

I'm working in this triple integral:

$ \int_R ln(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 )dV $ at the domaine R $ \{(x,y,z) | z>0  \text{ and } x^2 + y^2 < z^2 \text{ and } x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1 \} $

So I've been suggested spherical coordinates:

$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \ln(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)drd\phi d\theta$

I'm quite unsure with regards to the order of the integrals. Now I just been thinking setting them in the x,y,z order was the most logical. But I can explain why. Would be very grateful if someone could explain if its correct and why/why not.

Comment: You're forgetting the Jacobian in the integrand.

Comment: You need to multiply by $r^{2}\sin(\phi)$

Comment: @Ninad: Thank you for replying. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: When you change coordinate systems you always need a Jacobian factor that comes with the $dV$ since $dxdydz\neq drd\theta d\varphi$

Answer (score 1):

So you have $x=\rho\cos\theta\sin\varphi$, $y=\rho\sin\theta\sin\varphi$, and $z=\rho\cos\varphi$. Then$$x^2+y^2+z^2\leqslant1\iff\rho^2\leqslant1$$and\begin{align}x^2+y^2\leqslant z^2&\iff\rho^2\sin^2\varphi\leqslant\rho^2\cos^2\varphi\\&\iff\sin^2\varphi\leqslant\cos^2\varphi\\&\iff\varphi\in\left[0,\frac\pi4\right]\cup\left[\frac{3\pi}4,\pi\right].\end{align}Since, furthermore, we have $z>0$, we have in fact that $\varphi\in\left[0,\frac\pi4\right]$.

So, you do\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\rho^2\sin(\varphi)\log(\rho^2)\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\varphi&=2\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\rho^2\log(\rho)\sin(\varphi)\,\mathrm d\rho\,\mathrm d\theta\,\mathrm d\varphi\\&=4\pi\left(\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin(\varphi)\,\mathrm d\varphi\right)\left(\int_0^1\rho^2\log(\rho)\,\mathrm d\rho\right).\end{align}